# Как получить имя переменной и вывести?

Tags: java

Необходимо вывести имя лучшего бомбардира. Как это можно сделать?

```
int ronaldo, morata, benzema, isko, james;

ronaldo = 25;
morata = 15;
benzema = 11;
isko = 10;
james = 8;

//  массив бомбардиров Реала
int[] strikers = {ronaldo, morata, benzema, isko, james};

//  УЗНАТЬ лучшего бомбардира
int bestStriker = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < strikers.length; i++) {
    if (bestStriker < strikers[i]) {
        bestStriker = strikers[i];
    } else {
        break;
    }
}

System.out.println("The best striker have scored: " + bestStriker);
```

В данном примере выводится только кол-во забитых мячей лучшим бомбардиром

Comment: Надо содержать это  в коллекции `ключ => значение`, чтобы знать кто где. А в данном случае никак не узнать имя. Точнее можно через рефлексию. Но это явный костыль и вам не по зубам)

Comment: Используйте enum (перечисления) с конструктором.

Comment: Используйте enum (перечисления) с конструктором.

Answer (score 1):

Вот вариант

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add(new Pair<>("ronaldo", 25));
list.add(new Pair<>("morata", 15));
list.add(new Pair<>("benzema", 11));
list.add(new Pair<>("isko", 10));
list.add(new Pair<>("james", 8));

String bestStriker = list.stream().max((p1, p2) -> p1.getValue().compareTo(p2.getValue())).get().getKey();
//  УЗНАТЬ лучшего бомбардира
System.out.println("The best striker have scored: " + bestStriker);
```